# Remote SSH connection with autostart virtual environment

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I need to make such possibility for remote users.

Remote user connects via SSH to my server. Then after connecting server runs some script that open virtual machine environment for this user.

It is possible to make it, or my idea is not correct?

Virtual environment in this case is some image of OS with desktop GUI and other pretty possibilities that I can not run directly on Linux or BSD.

This virtual environment working with database that has no ports of it's interface to the Linux or any of BSD.

How to make possibility for remote users to connect to my server and work with this database with or not with running a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about this incredible virtual-machine.

But you can run scripts by just changing /bin/bash in /etc/passwd for the user to the script and making it executable, sometimes you need to put it on /etc/shells too.